# Which of these would most likely be a strong electrolyte?

Tags: solubility

1. An ionic compound
2. A covalent compound
3. A polar compound
4. A nonpolar compound

Previously, I have been taught that polar compounds can be either strong or weak electrolytes. I also learned that ionic compounds are generally strong. Therefore, my guess would be a, an ionic compound. However, I am not entirely sure of my answers. Could you please explain to me how I could confirm and get the right answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You are right. Ionic compound are strong electrolytes if they are soluble in water. $\ce{CaF2, BaSO4}$ are ionic compounds, but they are not soluble in water. I would not consider them as strong electrolytes. On the other hand, ionic compounds are a part of the bigger family of the polar compounds. But polar compounds are not always strong electrolytes. $\ce{CO, H2S, HF, H2O}$ are polar, but they are not strong electrolytes.

Answer (score 2):

Critically looking at it, Ionic compound(metals+non-metals) are strong electrolytes as they are able to conduct electricity when in molten form and that's a characteristic of a good and strong  electrolytes(Ability to conduct electricity) but polar solvent have the ability of being a strong electrolytes(very rare)  and weak electrolytes. Polar solvent when separated will have partial positive and partial negative charge.

Ionic compound are strong electrolytes than any other mentioned  compounds in your question.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you so much!